# How to link TKinter user form to excel for data collection?

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, user-input, export-to-excel

How to collect data from Tkinter user form? (either in excel or text file)

For example:

How to write value of following variable i.e. **a** (value needed:'x1') to an excel sheet?

```
a=StringVar()
checkBox1=Checkbutton(root, text="text1", variable=a, onvalue="x1", offvalue="N/A")
checkBox1.place(relx=0., rely=0., relwidth=0., relheight=0.)
checkBox1.pack()
```

My Python Understanding level: Beginner

Python version: 2.7.3

GUI: Tkinter

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, the best way of linking tkinter to excel is to work some hours throu the python docs, then a tkinter tutorial, while at the same time googling and studying code from others. Thats the faster way.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067404/how-to-export-user-inputs-from-python-to-excel-worksheet (third time in the past 24 hours)

Comment: sorry for the confusion caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

1. you can save your values as a csv file and them import it in excel (thats the fastest way)
2. for 1. you can use the python csv module that has a specific excel format.
3. you can use [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt/0.7.4) module (not available for python 3)
4. you can use [openpyxl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/1.5.8) (for new xlsx files)
5. you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (pandas uses xlwt or openpyxl)
6. you can use [tablib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tablib)
7. you can use a com object with [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Comment: thanks for the guidance. Now I am able to export user inputs in text boxes to excel, but the same methods is not working for Checkbox and radiobutton. If it is not too much trouble can you give me a sample code or an example? (For text entry inputs, I am using get() method, and then sheet.write() method to do this)