# What is wrong with this "file Open" code?

Tags: python, excel, user-interface

I am not able to open an excel file to write data using following code in python 2.7.3. 
What is wrong with this code?

```
def openfile():
    import os
    f=open('ab.xls', 'w')
    return

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100')

button1=Button(root, text='Open file', command=openfile)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: A return statement that doesn't return anything is redundant. It's worth noting that you should try to use
[the `with` statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)
when opening files in Python. This is both more readable and removes the
possibility of a file being left unclosed (even when exceptions occur). This won't fix your problem, but it's good practice.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include what exactly happens when you run this code, and what are you expecting it to do.

Comment: try "wb" maybe? I kinda doubt thats your issue though ,and what is the error?

Comment: This code works. It doesn't do anything useful but at least, it doesn't generate exceptions. Please elaborate on what you what to do.

Comment: Thanks Lattyware for your suggestion. @yasar11732 & JoranB: There are no error msgs. Just to inform I am using Wing IDE for writing this code.

Comment: @Xion: Are you able to open an excel file with this code? This is a trial code for opening an excel file. Basically, I want to open an LP optimization model database.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, you're opening a file, but you aren't storing it anywhere. `f` is immediately forgotten when the function ends. Is that the problem? Or is an exception being thrown?

Comment: I think the issue here is you are expecting something to happen - all you do is open a file and do nothing with it. Why would anything happen? All this will do is create the file when you press the button.

Comment: I tried it with xlwt package, even then no excel file pops up.

Comment: @senderle: no exceptions are shown. My code and ab.xls both are on my desktop is that a issue? just checking

Comment: @mrn, are you expecting a window full of columns and rows to pop up when you "open" the file? Cause that's not going to happen unless you write a _lot_ more code.

Comment: or is it because I am trying to open .xls file in excel 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what open means in this context. `open()` is a function that returns a file handle in Python so you can read the data into your application.

If you want to open the file with the default program on your system for that filetype, look into [os.startfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile).

Comment: @mrn When using new commands, I suggest you look at the Python documentation. It's really clear and well written, and almost always gives examples. It's worth a look as it makes stuff like this much more obvious.

Comment: I have learned my lesson from this. In future I will check the documentation first. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Putting `import os` inside the function means it doesn't get imported until you run the function... probably not what you want.
2. You open the file, but never return a handle to it. Try replacing `return` with `return f`
3. If you are using `import xlwt`, you don't need this anyway; it takes care of writing to a file. See my previous response at [How to export user inputs (from python) to excel worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067404/how-to-export-user-inputs-from-python-to-excel-worksheet)

**Edit:**

... 'ab.xls' was opened, you returned a handle to it, and then *do nothing with it*. What did you *expect* it to do, exactly?

Try

```
import Tkinter as tk

def do_something_with_file():
    with open('ab.xls', 'w') as f:
        print("The file is open")
        # --> now DO SOMETHING with it <--

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100')
button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Open file', command=do_something_with_file)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd option but no result i.e. ab.xls did not open. Regarding 3rd, can I open already existing file with xlwt? I tried it with xlrd too but no luck.

Comment: @mrn I think you are confused about what opening means. It means the file has a handle in Python, ready for reading the data, not that it will open a program to handle the file. If you want that, it's something totally different.

Comment: @Lattyware:oh. you are right. I got confused. I am completely new to this. Basically, I am a mathematician. But I am trying to build a small interface so that every time I don't have to formulate my linear programming model.

Comment: @mrn See my answer for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your "f" variable is a file object that is a local variable (destroyed as soon as the "openfile" function ends).  You can either declare f as global, or have your openfile function return the file object.

Answer (score -1):

i can't see any obvious fatal errors in this code.

going out on a limb here, especially if you are running this on windows, is the file perhaps still open somewhere else, like in excel or through your own code? you can not open a file for writing if it already is open for writing elsewhere.