# How to export a list with different size from python to excel

Tags: python, excel, export

I already read [Export a Python List to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766833/export-a-python-list-to-excel) and [How to export user inputs (from python) to excel worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067404/how-to-export-user-inputs-from-python-to-excel-worksheet), but the different is that my list is in more than one size. I mean my list is something like this:

```
List=[[list1],[list2],...,[list10]]
```

list1, list2,...,list10 are including of 3 numbers with float46 formats. For example:

```
list1=[1.34543324545676,2.4354356645454,2.786434355455]
list2=[3.33434342343423,6.6566665655655,7.343545454545]
```

...

```
list10=[3.6565656565465,7.45454536565656,7.56565656565]
```

I want to export the List to an Excel file that *list1* is in the first column, *list2* is in the second column, ..., *list10* is in the tenth column.

Comment: these list are of irregular length? What do you want to do with indexes that are not there in some lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fine with using `csv` module to write to a csv, and then open it up in excel, then you can use `csv` module along with `zip()`   , to write out your list of lists as columns. Example -

```
import csv
with open('<excel file>','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    #writer.writerow([<header row>]) #uncomment this and put header, if you want header row , if not leave it commented.
    for x in zip(*list_of_lists):
        writer.writerow(x)
```

The `*list_of_list` unpacks the lists and sends each inner list as a separate argument to `zip()` and zip() combines each list at each index so first list output of `zip()` is the 0th index of all lists, etc. So this basically transposes the list of lists.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import csv
>>> ll = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[4,2,1]]
>>> with open('a.csv','w') as f:
...     writer = csv.writer(f)
...     for x in zip(*ll):
...         writer.writerow(x)
...
```

Output in `a.csv` is -

```
1,3,4

2,4,2

3,5,1
```

---

I think something similar (using `zip()` ) can be done for other excel libraries as well, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) module that will automatically handle different list lengths:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

list1 = [1.34543324545676, 2.4354356645454, 2.786434355455]
list2 = [3.33434342343423, 6.6566665655655, 7.343545454545]
list3 = [3.6565656565465,  7.45454536565656, 7.56565656565]         

List  = [list1, list2, list3]

row_num = 0

for col_num, data in enumerate(List):
    worksheet.write_column(row_num, col_num, data)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]