# From list of list to file in Python

Tags: python, database, list

Imagine a set of data like `APT=[[10.2,5,6],[9.2,-7,8],[5.75,1,2]]` and I want to export as a file (I don't care if it's `.txt`, `.xslx` or `.csv`) with a header `['APT','WN','WE']`.

I want the file to be well shaped (a table like

APT | WN | WE

10.2 | 5 | 6

9.2 | -7 | 8

5.75 | 1 | 2

I've tried diferent things, such as

```
with open("file.csv",'w') as f:
    wri= csv.writer(f)
    wri.writerow(["ATP","WN","WE"])
    for element in zip(*APT):
        wri.writerow(element)
```

and also the function `to_excel` from `Pandas` and none of them work as I want.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

PS: Sorry, I don't know how to add better tables in StackOverflow

PS1: I've read [How to export a list with different size from python to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978283/how-to-export-a-list-with-different-size-from-python-to-excel) but I don't get the proper file shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pandas` package has a method, which is designed specifically for your task: `to_csv()`.

Here's your code:

```
# import module
import pandas as pd
# convert your data to DataFrame
df= pd.DataFrame(APT)
# name columns
df.columns = ['APT','WN','WE']
# save DataFrame as .csv
df.to_csv('apt.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` for that.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(APT)
df.columns = ['APT','WN','WE']
```

This will give you:

```
>>> df
     APT  WN  WE
0  10.20   5   6
1   9.20  -7   8
2   5.75   1   2
```

You can then export it to `.csv` with built-in function `to_csv()` like this:

```
df.to_csv('name_of_the_file', sep=';')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-Pandas solution for you as well. You were not far from a final solution already:

```
with open("file.csv",'w') as f:
    wri= csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    wri.writerow(["ATP","WN","WE"])
    wri.writerows(APT)    # csv.writerows takes any iterable (your outer list) and goes through the iterables that it contains (the inner lists) and creates CSV lines from it.
```

Please check the [Python CSV module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) for further CSV format parameters. This includes configuration options for quotations as well as delimiters.

This is the output file that you would have gotten with the above code:

```
ATP;WN;WE
10.2;5;6
9.2;-7;8
5.75;1;2
```

With a different delimiter setting (e.g. `'\t'`for the tab character) you can even get nice looking tables like this:

```
ATP WN  WE
10.2    5   6
9.2 -7  8
5.75    1   2
```